# Probability and Combinations Question-Without Replacement.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 30 biscuits in a box. 12 are wrapped and the other 18 aren't. If I were to take 4 biscuits without replacement from the box, what is the probability that I take exactly 2 wrapped biscuits?

*W=wrapped, U=unwrapped*

**My method:**

WWUU+WUWU+UUWW+UWUW+WUWW+UWWU
so

(12/30 * 11/29 * 18/28 * 17/27 )+...etc.

**However the answer was simple:**

12/30 * 11/29 * 18/28 * 17/27 * 4C2

Now I know that 4C2=6, but this implies that each WWUU,WUWU...for 6 times (my method) have the same probability. Why is that so? Can anyone explain what the answer's logic is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"but this implies that each WWUU,WUWU etc have the same probability. "

They do in fact have the same probability. If you write out the probabilities of each string, you'll find that they are in fact equal; the numerators and the denominators are the same:

e.g. $\frac{12}{30} \cdot \frac{11}{29} \cdot \frac{18}{28} \cdot \frac{17}{27}=\frac{18}{30} \cdot \frac{17}{29} \cdot \frac{12}{28} \cdot \frac{11}{27}=\frac{18 \cdot 17 \cdot 12 \cdot 11}{30 \cdot 29 \cdot 28 \cdot 27} $

The $\binom{4}{2}$ term is then simply used to add up the probability of each string ( WWUU, WUWU,...etc) occurring to get the total probability.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So why couldn't they just multiply by 6 instead of 4C2?

Comment: Math textbooks usually want to confuse you. For example, if the answer was 2 * log base 10 of 6, they could write it as log base 10 of 36. Or, they could have done that to show you **how** they got the 6.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, $\binom{4}{2}=6$ so they did multiply by 6. The reason that you multiply the probability by a factor of $\binom{4}{2}$ is because the letters W,W,U,U can be arranged in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, which gives us the strings that you listed before: WWUU+WUWU+UUWW+UWUW+WUWW+UWWU, which all have the same probability.

But yes, you could just as easily write 6 instead of $\binom{4}{2}$ and that would be fine, as you pointed out.

Comment: @user9856 They use $4$C$2$ because that is the application of the general formula for the number of strings. Once you understand the formula, you don't have to write the entire list out. Then you can easily solve problems such as the probability that if you take $14$ biscuits from the box, exactly $6$ of them will be wrapped. (The number of strings then is $14$C$6$.)

Comment: So would it be like this?:

4C2=arranging 2 wrapped biscuits in 4 slots?

Comment: 2 wrapped biscuits and 2 unwrapped biscuits. Yes, precisely, the binomial coefficient is, as David K pointed out, a way of listing out all the possible strings that might be formed. So then you just need to calculate the probability of 1 string, and then multiply by the number of strings, as they all have the same probability.